# How does scoping work in Perl modules?

Tags: perl, module, scoping

I don't really understand how scoping works in Perl modules. This doesn't print anything. I would like it if running a.pl printed 1

b.pm

```
$f=1;
```

a.pl

```
use b;

print $f
```

Comment: Coping with Scoping is an excellent article about scoping in Perl.  http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Namespaces.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, you have a lot of misconceptions that we can best address by fixing your immediate problem and pointing you to good resources.

b.pm should be:

```
package b;
our $f = 1;
1;
```

a.pl should be

```
use b;
print $b::f
```

run the whole thing with `perl -I. a.pl`

Now go read `perldoc`[`perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) very carefully.

Also read `perldoc`[`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

Comment: `strict` and `warnings` for the `win`.

Comment: Although this technically works, it's usually the wrong design for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should start off by reading about Perl modules in the manual: `perldoc perlmod` at the commandline, or go to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Most probably because you're running this code on a case-insensitive file system, where asking for the module `b` loads the built-in module [`B`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html).  Your module is not getting loaded at all.  If you rename `b`, you get the result you expect.

The longer answer included lots of chiding for failing to observe even minimal good practice, and has been elided.

Comment: -1 Perl's packages are case sensitive, so the compiler backend `B.pm` is not called at all.  renaming the package will not solve the problem

Comment: @Eric Depends on the platform. The Windows filesystem is case-insensitive, for example.

Comment: However, it is true that naming packages with lower-cased names is not a best practice, and the variables $a and $b are treated differently.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. If OP changes `b.pm` to `c.pm` and `use b` to `use c`, then both files are operating on the global variable `$f` and the program works as he expected.

Comment: To test whether this is correct, OP should run: `use b; print $INC{'b.pm'}` and see where the `b` module is loaded from. On Cygwin, I get: `/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/b.pm` -- the core B module.

Comment: nice!  on Mac it's `/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level/b.pm`

Comment: @mobrule in the original question, `$f` wouldn't be in scope regardless of whether or not the right b.pm was loaded. The unfortunate choice of the name `b` might be *part* of the problem, but it's not the biggest part.

Comment: @hobbs - try it out. In the absence of any `my`, `our`, `local`, and `package` declarations, both files refer to the same `$f` variable in the main symbol table

Comment: mobrule is right about why this works this way.  Everyone who claims it doesn't should try it out on a platform with a case-insensitive file system.  My test platform was OS X, and I hadn't consciously thought of its deceptive case-insensitivity ("Grargh!  It looks like *nix!  Why does it hate me?"), but that explains why `B` is loaded when I ask for `b` to my satisfaction.  On my Debian environment, the OP's code works as he expected it to in the first place.

Comment: @mobrule apologies... `use` ing a file without a `package` declaration in it is so far outside of my everyday experience that my brain didn't even process it :)

Comment: No worries, hobbs. There's lots of things in this post to make you do a double take.